Error: Failed to interpolate TextStyles with different inherit values
I have an app where i have dark and light mode and when i try to use another app with keeping my app in background it shows "Failed to interpolate TextStyles with different inherit values".
Below are the code for light theme and dark theme:
static ThemeData lightTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: AppColors.primaryColor),
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColorLight,

      // Define other light theme properties here
    );
  }

  static ThemeData darkTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
            seedColor: AppColors.primaryColorOpacity50,
            brightness: Brightness.dark),
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColorDark,
        timePickerTheme: TimePickerThemeData(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.labelGrayColor,
          dayPeriodColor: AppColors.primaryColorOpacity50,
          helpTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          confirmButtonStyle:
              TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.black),
          cancelButtonStyle: TextButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
        ) // Define other dark theme properties here
        );
  }

How can i fix this issue?
tried to remove the dark theme and app works fine and vice versa but issue occur when i use both the themes.

Can you share a Github repo link with sample project to reproduce the issue?

Try to replace textTheme of darkTheme with textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
